# Select distinct on one column and return all other columns

Tags: sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

I'm trying to find distinct orders based on the modified date. I want to sort it and find the latest modified order.

I tried to do as in postgreSQL. 
`select distinct on (orders) * from the table`;
But this throws an error in case of mariaDB

```
Orders          Modified Date
------          ---------------
23031185    2019-09-24 19:36:51
23031185    2019-09-24 22:01:57
23031185    2019-09-24 19:32:28
23031185    2019-09-24 19:33:25
23031185    2019-09-24 19:33:18



The expected output should be the latest one 

Orders          Modified Date
------          ---------------
23031185    2019-09-24 22:01:57
```

I also have other columns. I need to get all distinct rows based on orders column with all other columns.

Comment: see the [groupwise-maximum] tag.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of MariaDB, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank the records by descending `modified_date` within groups sharing the same `orders`, and then filter on the top record per group:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY orders ORDER BY modified_date DESC) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.orders = t.orders AND t1.modified_date > t.modified_date
)
```

Or you can use a subquery to return the max date per group and join on it:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE modified_date = (
    SELECT MAX(t1.modified_date)
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.orders = t.orders
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it simply

```
SELECT  Orders,
        MAX(Modified Date) AS LatestDate
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Orders;
```